# One-sided configuration with custom column names

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm having trouble finding the right combination of Fluent methods to map my classes appropriately. Here's basically what I'm trying to do:

```
Person table: PersonID, HomeAddressID (nullable), WorkAddressID (nullable)
Address table: AddressID, Street, etc...
```

The `Person` class has an `Address HomeAddress` and an `Address WorkAddress` property, but not the integer properties for the IDs.

The `Address` class does not have any properties for its related `Person` entities.

I'm not finding any examples online for this scenario, and I'm just not finding the right combination. Code-first configuration has always done a good job confusing me.

This is the closest to one of the examples I found, but I'm getting `Invalid column name 'HomeAddressID'`, which tells me I'm probably mapping the wrong side of the relationship.

```
public class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    // other mappings

    HasOptional(p => p.HomeAddress)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal()
        .Map(x => x.MapKey("HomeAddressID"));
    HasOptional(p => p.WorkAddress)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal()
        .Map(x => x.MapKey("WorkAddressID"));    
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add the HomeAddress and WorkAddress ids to the person class? If so, this works for me...

```
public class Person
{
        public int? HomeAddressID { get; set; }
        private Address _homeAddress;
        public Address HomeAddress
        {
            get { return _homeAddress; }
            set
            {
                _homeAddress= value;
                HomeAddressID = value != null ? (int?)value.HomeAddressID : null;
            }
        }
}

public class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    HasOptional(a => a.HomeAddress).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.HomeAddressID);
}
```

Comment: Looks like that works, thanks, but I am purposely not exposing those properties. In real life, this is an updatable view, and the underlying column is not updated using the view's trigger. I don't want to make it look like the developer can assign a value to that column and expect it to save.